# Issue using certbot with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm actually working on a webapp, I use `Reactjs` for the frontend and `Golang` for the backend. Those 2 programs are hosted separately on 2 VMs on `Google-Compute-Engine`. I want to serve my app through `https` so I choose to use `Nginx` for serving the frontend in production. Firstly I made my config file for `Nginx`:

```
#version: nginx/1.14.0 (ubuntu)
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

     root /var/www/banshee;
     server_name XX.XXX.XX.XXX; #public IP of my frontend VM

     index index.html;

     location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html =404;
     }
   }
```

For this part everything works as expected but after that I want to serve my App over `https` following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-server-react-on-nginx-over-https-162c64dcc1e5). I installed the packages `software-properties-common`,`python-certbot-apache`
 and `certbot` but when I tried

`sudo cerbot --nginx certonly`

I get the following message:

```
gdes@frontend:/etc/nginx$ sudo certbot --nginx certonly
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Could not choose appropriate plugin: The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed
The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed
```

I made some searches on Google and here and I still can't figure out which plugin is missing or an other way to fix this.

Does someone have an idea tohelp me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The plugin is called `certbot-nginx` under Manjaro

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I was trying to create Let's Encrypt certificate using certbot for my sub-domain and had the following issue.
**Command:**

> ubuntu@localhost:~$ certbot --nginx -d my_subdomain.website.com -d my_subdomain2.website.com

**Issue:**

> The requested Nginx plugin does not appear to be installed

**Solution:**

Ubuntu 20+

> ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx

Earlier Versions

> ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 the package name is `python3-certbot-nginx`

Comment: You you installed via pip, you can alternatively do `pip install certbot-nginx`

Comment: The solution for Ubuntu 20+ worked on Ubuntu 18 as well.

Answer (score 25):

You will need to replace

```
apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

by

```
apt install python3-certbot-nginx
```

Answer (score 8):

You can install the Certbot nginx plugin with the following commands:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
apt update
apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but the installation keeps failing when I do `sudo certbot --nginx certonly` I think it's because my app doesn't have any DNS

Comment: Yes, the domain name needs to resolve to the server running certbot in order to verify that you own the domain.

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-install a python3 version of Lets Encrypt's certbot.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 10, `certbot` returns a "could not find a usable nginx binary" issue because, "/usr/sbin" is missing from the PATH. Add /usr/sbin to the PATH

```
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

Then `certbot` can make a certificate for nginx

```
certbot --nginx -d <server name> --post-hook "/usr/sbin/service nginx restart"
```

As explained on the [debian wiki page for letsencrypt](https://wiki.debian.org/LetsEncrypt).

Answer (score 0):

To install `certbot` inside Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance do the following:

```bash
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```